# How to use data stored in sharedpreferences from non-activity class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to get and update the data which I stored in sharedpreferences xml file from a non-activity class.But I dont know how to reach the data stored in sharedPreferences from a non-activity class in android.In my activiy class i can store data in sharedprefences and i also can retrive these data in my activiy class. However i can not retrive these data from a non-activiy class. My code is below.Thank you...

```
    mSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("storageforfavorite", 0);
    mPrefsEditor = mSharedPrefs.edit();

    for(int i= 0;i<names.size();i++){
        mPrefsEditor.putString(indexForFav[i],"0"); 
    }
    mPrefsEditor.commit();

    for(int i=0;i<names.size();i++){
        String keyForFav=mSharedPrefs.getString(indexForFav[i], "2");
        valueForFav.add(keyForFav);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is have access to the Context object.
So if you want to use sharedPreferences inside an object, maybe you should pass a Context object in the class constructor. Doing this way you can do this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to pass a `Context` to be able to access `SharedPreferences` from a non-`Activity` class.

Example:

```
// mContext => Context-object passed from calling Activity
SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("storageforfavorite", 0);
```