# save data in nonactivity class from another nonactivity class and fetch data from activity class in android

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

i have one class (named data_key class) in which i am using sharedpreferences for sharing data.
this class is accessible in other class called MODEL.
the MODEL class is accessible in all other project and activities.

I am new to android programming so kindly help plz.
i want to add data in data_key class and access that in model class, so that other activity classes can access the data.

kindly help plz.
i have tried with the example in below link.

[Access SharedPreferences from another class (non-activity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536303/access-sharedpreferences-from-another-class-non-activity)

Comment: Not able to understand your problem clearly. Do you want to access SharedPreferences from Activity or NonActivity ?

Comment: Do you want the stored data to be accessible in an Activity using model right? First you should know how to store data ["See this"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) after that you can loop through data using that model class anywhere in you Application

Comment: @AbidKhan i want to save the data but at runtime not static way, which is given in this link.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences are related to context. You can only reference it through a context.

You can simply pass context as a parameter to your class (Model). For example in the constructor.

If your **data_key** class is an Activity do:
`Model model = new Model(this);`
If not, then send the *context* by which you access the *SharedPreference*
`Model model = new Model (mContext);`